# Create postgres database from pony ORM

Tags: python, postgresql, ponyorm

Is it possible to create a new database from pony ORM? We couldn't find it within pony ORM docs, it's always assumed the database exists or is using SQLite file.

We would like to create a testing database and drop it afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Per:

https://docs.ponyorm.org/api_reference.html#sqlite

Supported databases

If you look at the .bind() API for the various databases, SQLite is the only one with create_db. This is because in SQLite creating a database is just creating a single file. The other engines need to go through their own program to initialize a database. You will need to create an independent script that creates the database.

Comment: We'll ressort to directly calling psycopg to create the database prior to pony.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your sqlite database file, you can try using [pgloader](https://pgloader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/sqlite.html).